# Has an ejection ever been reversed?

Tags: baseball, officiating

Most times when a player is ejected from the game by an ump, they attempt to argue their case. Has this ever lead to an ejection being reversed?

Comment: I highly doubt it.

Comment: Being ejected for dissent, and the ejection overturned by more dissent? I don't think so - just on principle. There might also be rules against recalling ejected staff/players unless they meet specific criteria..

Comment: I don't know about baseball but in the NBA a player can be ejected and upon review for example a flagrant can be down graded. Player does not get fined.

Comment: It is my understanding that baseball arguments are all for the **next** call - if you manage to win the argument and convince the ump it was wrong, the next close one will go your way. To that end most of the time the **real** arguing starts after the ejection when there is nothing more to lose. Also sometimes managers argue a lot to cheer up their players without risking the players being ejected for arguing.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no mechanism for an ejection to be overturned.  An ejection is usually done for unsportsmanlike behavior.  It is really at the umpires discretion.  There is also no mechanism nor any rule that would garner the league reviewing an objection.  In the NBA they have league rules that after so many tech/flagrant fouls you miss a game, in baseball there are no rules like this.

Probably the closest thing I can think of is George Brett's pine tar bat incident.  His home run was disallowed and then protested.  The Royals won the protest and the game restarted after his home run.  What most people probably don't realize is he was ejected from that game too - after the game was over.  So MLB ruled that their umpires were incorrect, causing the argument, and the damn game was over but his ejection that was never announced to him during the game was upheld by the league.

Answer (score 0):

No, generally when you argue with an umpire, you are actually arguing a play or call on the field, and you are ejected for arguing that too much or saying something that you should not have said. Therefore, there is a chance you could get the call reversed now with replay, but they will never undo an ejection of a player or coach.

In the current baseball age, you won't get much arguing on a play that can be challenged simply because they know that to be the case, and that there is a chance for it to be overturned. You can still argue after the review if you still disagree. But once you are ejected, you are ejected. They have never reversed that. The only thing that happens after an ejection are fines or umpire reviews in the days following (if necessary in either case).